# Chrome 37 doesn't support Calibri Light

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Yesterday was my site ok, but today when I turned it on, weird things happened. I'm using Calibri Light font on my site a lot, but it was replaced with default font. Also width of inputs changed. How can I fix this? I read somewhere that Chrome from version 37 doesn't support fonts with space in their names, like Arial Bold, or Calibri Light, but I don't know what to do with that information, since I were using Calibri Light that was built in chrome. Is there a fix for it?

Edit:It solved itself, probably bug.

Comment: Noted here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-wdLTQk4Y_M

Comment: Yes, but without solution.

Comment: There may not be a solution until they put out a bug fix (if it is indeed a bug).

Comment: "Open Sans" has spaces in it and it works as expected. Does not have anything to do with space. Also, do the fonts appear OK in FF and IE?

Answer (score 2):

Calibri is a Microsoft font.  It can usually also be found on OSX stored in this directory

```
/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Calibri.ttf
```

If you want to use it.  The font should be written capitalized..

```
body { font-family: 'Calibri Light','Gill Sans','Open Sans',Geneva,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
```

If it's not loading, you should just include it.  You would need to host the Calibri font files with your website and include them..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri Light';
    src: url('/fonts/calibri_light.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/calibri_light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/calibri_light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/calibri_light.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/calibri_light.svg#CustomFont') format('svg');
}
```

Whereever you read that Chrome does not support font's with spaces in their name.. I'm not sure I believe that.  I searched the [Chromium forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!search/fonts$20with$20space$20in$20name) and could not find any topics on the subject..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re relying on the user having Calibri Light installed on their system? You could also use CSS to serve it as a web font, which seems to work in the latest Chrome.

It’s available here: http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/calibri/light though not free.

I went to http://typecast.com/preview/fontscom/431781:1371185 and changed the weight of one of the elements to Light, and on Chrome 37 it worked for me. I don’t have Calibri Light installed on my machine.

Comment: I tried it with @font-face, but it was clearly different that Chrome default Calibri Light. I'll try that trick with font weight, thanks.